# Emberjs Ember-Data return multiple records with store.find while using a parameter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I need to make a request to a non-standardized API in the form of:

`http://host.com/(parameter)/path`

I can make the correct call by using `buildURL: function(record, suffix) {}` and forcing it to use the correct syntax, but because I have to pass in a parameter ("suffix") during the store.find call:

```
this.store.find('model', parameter);
```

ember thinks I'm looking to get a single record back when in reality the REST response includes many records.  I tried to simply pass it through to findMany, but still received errors.

Any suggestions?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you're looking for the namespace of the RESTAdapter:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 14,
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'whatever/you/need',
    host: 'host.com'
  })
});
```

Or if you need to make a dynamic path:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 14,
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: function() { return 'whatever/you/need'; }.property(),
    host: 'host.com'
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  I had looked at trying to use namespace before, but how would I go about passing in the dynamic path I need it to be set to?

Comment: I don't know.. Sorry. Here's how I'm using the namespace. namespace: function() { return "api/v1/forums/" + window.forumId; }.property()

Comment: I thought about using something global in the dom, but I'm going to need to potentially do this for a lot of stuff (I guess I could do a stack).  Just seems like not a very clean solution.  And thus far I've been impressed with how clean an implementation ember has had.  So it feels like I'm missing something.